# Shifting and aligning text with a picture in a CV heading

Tags: tabularx, cv, alignment

I am trying to adjust the heading portion of this particular CV template according to the picture with arrows for an alignment with dashed lines as well as adding another properly aligned column for text as shown in the red box.

However, the template uses tabularx package. I am not familiar with it in order to define the environment to achieve these alignments.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{b{#1}}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,top=1.2cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}


% Defining sections
\newenvironment{rSection}[1]  % Section name
    { 
        \sectionskip
        \MakeUppercase{\bfseries #1} % 2nd title
        \sectionlineskip
        \hrule % Horizontal line
        \begin{list}{}{ % List for each individual item in the section
             \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.1em} % Margin within the section
    }
                \item[]
                        }{
          \end{list}
    }


% Defining whitespaces. Can be \smallskip, \medskip or \bigskip
\def\sectionlineskip{\medskip} % The space above the horizontal line for each section 
\def\sectionskip{\medskip} % The space after the heading section




\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xl}
    {\Large\bfseries Name Surname \par}     & \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image}
    \\ 
    Info \par
    More info \par
    More, more info
\end{tabularx}
\bigbreak


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Education}

{\bfseries University of California} \hfill { \bfseries Location} \\ 
{} \hfill {\em XXXX-XXXX} \\ 
B.S. in Computer Science \& Engineering \\
Minor in Linguistics Minor in Linguistics  \smallskip \\
Member of Eta Kappa Nu \\
Member of Upsilon Pi Epsilon \\
Overall GPA: 5.678

\end{rSection}




%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE FORMATTING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newenvironment{rSubsection}[4]{ % 4 input arguments - company name, year(s) employed, job title and location
 {\bfseries #1} \hfill {#2} % Bold company name and date on the right
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{ % If the third argument is not specified, don't print the job title and location line
  \\
  {\em #3} \hfill {\em #4} % Italic job title and location
  }\smallskip
  \begin{list}{$\cdot$}{\leftmargin=0em} % \cdot used for bullets, no indentation
   \itemsep -0.5em \vspace{-0.5em} % Compress items in list together for aesthetics
  }{
  \end{list}
  \vspace{0.5em} % Some space after the list of bullet points
}




%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Experience}

\begin{rSubsection}{ACME, Inc}{October 2010 - Present}{Web Developer}{Palo Alto, CA}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus.
\item Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero Adobe Coldfusion egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue.
\item Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem Microsoft SQL lacinia consectetur.
\item Donec ut libero sed arcu vehicula ultricies a non tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\item Pellentesque auctor nisi id magna consequat JavaScript sagittis.
\item Aliquam at massa ipsum. Quisque bash bibendum purus convallis nulla ultrices ultricies.
\end{rSubsection}

\end{rSection}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use three `minipage` environments with each taking up a third of the space. Then, insert your table in the left one, the second table in the middle one and the image in the last minipage (keep in mind that you need to use `\hfill` to make the image right-aligned).

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{b{#1}}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,top=1.2cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% Defining sections
\newenvironment{rSection}[1]  % Section name
    { 
        \sectionskip
        \MakeUppercase{\bfseries #1} % 2nd title
        \sectionlineskip
        \hrule % Horizontal line
        \begin{list}{}{ % List for each individual item in the section
             \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.1em} % Margin within the section
    }
                \item[]
                        }{
          \end{list}
    }

% Defining whitespaces. Can be \smallskip, \medskip or \bigskip
\def\sectionlineskip{\medskip} % The space above the horizontal line for each section 
\def\sectionskip{\medskip} % The space after the heading section

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\textwidth}\vspace{0pt}% Left column
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X}
    {\Large\bfseries Name Surname \par}
    \\ 
    Info \par
    More info \par
    More, more info
  \end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\textwidth}\vspace{0pt}% Middle column
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X}
    {\Large\bfseries Second Column \par} 
    \\ 
    Second col info \par
    Second col more info \par
    More, more info
  \end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}[t]{0.34\textwidth}\vspace{0pt}% Right column
\noindent\hfill\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image}
\end{minipage}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain what you want with a minimal number of modifications: don't redefine the `X` columns and use the key  `valign=t` (defined bu `adjustbox`) for the placement of the image. I added another `X` column for the additional information.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,top=1.2cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

% Defining sections
\newenvironment{rSection}[1] % Section name
    {
        \sectionskip
        \MakeUppercase{\bfseries #1} % 2nd title
        \sectionlineskip
        \hrule % Horizontal line
        \begin{list}{}{ % List for each individual item in the section
             \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.1em} % Margin within the section
    }
                \item[]
                        }{
          \end{list}
    }

% Defining whitespaces. Can be \smallskip, \medskip or \bigskip
\def\sectionlineskip{\medskip} % The space above the horizontal line for each section
\def\sectionskip{\medskip} % The space after the heading section

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXl}
    {\Large\bfseries Name Surname \par} Info \par
    More info \par
    More, more info
    &Info \par
    More info \par
    More, more info
    & \includegraphics[height=4cm, valign=t]{pepe-le-pew2}%width=3cm,
\end{tabularx}
\bigbreak

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Education}

{\bfseries University of California} \hfill { \bfseries Location} \\
{} \hfill {\em XXXX-XXXX} \\
B.S. in Computer Science \& Engineering \\
Minor in Linguistics Minor in Linguistics \smallskip \\
Member of Eta Kappa Nu \\
Member of Upsilon Pi Epsilon \\
Overall GPA: 5.678

\end{rSection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% WORK EXPERIENCE FORMATTING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newenvironment{rSubsection}[4]{ % 4 input arguments - company name, year(s) employed, job title and location
 {\bfseries #1} \hfill {#2} % Bold company name and date on the right
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{ % If the third argument is not specified, don't print the job title and location line
  \\
  {\em #3} \hfill {\em #4} % Italic job title and location
  }\smallskip
  \begin{list}{$\cdot$}{\leftmargin=0em} % \cdot used for bullets, no indentation
   \itemsep -0.5em \vspace{-0.5em} % Compress items in list together for aesthetics
  }{
  \end{list}
  \vspace{0.5em} % Some space after the list of bullet points
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% WORK EXPERIENCE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Experience}

\begin{rSubsection}{ACME, Inc}{October 2010 - Present}{Web Developer}{Palo Alto, CA}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus.
\item Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero Adobe Coldfusion egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue.
\item Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem Microsoft SQL lacinia consectetur.
\item Donec ut libero sed arcu vehicula ultricies a non tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\item Pellentesque auctor nisi id magna consequat JavaScript sagittis.
\item Aliquam at massa ipsum. Quisque bash bibendum purus convallis nulla ultrices ultricies.
\end{rSubsection}

\end{rSection}

\end{document}
```

[image]